# Maximum getProgramAccounts returned bytes

Tags: rpc, getprogramaccounts

What is usually the limit of accounts/bytes returned by getProgramAccounts?

For example, if I have 100,000 accounts with 40 bytes each, would getProgramAccounts return them all?

I’ve read that the limit is 10MB, but then also read that RPC providers may cap it.

So I’m not sure which number to use as the limit in order to correctly design the structure of my accounts.

Has this limit changed lately?

Comment: You could try with TokenProgram and see what happens. Might depend on rpc provider

Comment: @JonasH. Right! That would be a good way to test it, will test that

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - do it in Rust, not Node. And deserialize with Borsh not serde JSON.

getProgramAccounts memcmp for the "User" account type for Drift (dRiftyHA39MWEi3m9aunc5MzRF1JYuBsbn6VPcn33UH) is about 150k accounts and 1.5Gb of memory.

Node couldn't handle it and broke (heap limit OOM).
So I tried a manual chunked and streamed request and bumped Node's heap to 16Gb. Still couldn't do it.

So I tried in Rust, and Rust swallowed that response in <2 seconds, held it all in memory, and iterated, filtered, and sorted in <30ms.

Last point is I initially used sol-chainsaw (https://crates.io/crates/sol-chainsaw) to deserialize the accounts using serde_json.
That 1.5Gb and 150k User accounts took 280 seconds on average.

Deserializing with Borsh instead took merely 800ms... Remember that Anchor accounts are serialized with Borsh, as the `AnchorSerialize` macro is `BorshSerialize` under the hood.

Comment: Nice, and wow, that’s a lot of bytes for a call. What RPC provider did you use for that?

Comment: HelloMoon enterprise and Helius free... it's not an RPC issue. It's a "handling that much data in memory" issue.